# How to update multiple activities from a single activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-sharedpreferences

What I would like to know is if there is a way to update multiple activities from one activity.

For example from my **activityC** (in my case EditProfileActivity) I update user profile. **activityC** is a child of **activityB**, which is a child of **activityA**, and open from mainActivity's navdrawer. I also have **activityE** that can be opened from **activityC** and **activityF** that can be open from **activityA**. I want to update all of them.

When I change a user name, photo, about or anything else, I want to send that changed information even without closing **activityC**. And if I go back or forward from it, it should have updated user information already. If user did not change anything it should not update those activities.

If it was only one activity I would do it via `intent` or `onActivityResult`.

Is there a way to do this without `shared preferences`, or `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use event bus for this purpose like [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) explained here:

you can create event like this:

```
public static class UpdateEvent { /* your getter and setter */   }
```

Prepare subscribers: Declare and annotate your subscribing method, optionally specify a thread mode:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onUpdateEvent(UpdateEvent event) {
   /* event fire here when you post event from other class or fragment */
  };
```

Register - unregister your subscriber.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);//Register 
 }

@Override
public void onStop() {
super.onStop();
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);//unregister
}
```

Fire events like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateEvent());
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can also use, and in my opinion is easier and better than EventBus, is to use a `LocalBroadcastManager`. It will allow you send broadcasts across your application which can be received by one or more activities. I guess it's pretty much what you want.

Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is `Broadcast Reciever`
Try this

In your other activity class declare this

```
BroadcastReceiver broadCastNewMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do your stuff here

        }
    };
```

Now in `onCreate()` register this

```
registerReceiver(this.broadCastNewMessage, new IntentFilter("bcNewMessage"));
```

And in `onDestroy()`

```
unregisterReceiver(broadCastNewMessage);
```

Now Call this method from the activity where u want to update other activity

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction("bcNewMessage"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set information in sharedprefences and can get fetch information in any activity

I have created this Class for saving object in sharedprefrences

```
public class DroidPrefs
{
     public static boolean contains(Context context, String key) {
     return getDefaultInstance(context).contains(key);
}

public static <T> T get(Context context, String key, Class<T> cls) {
    return getDefaultInstance(context).get(key, cls);
}

public static void apply(Context context, String key, Object value) {
    getDefaultInstance(context).apply(key, value);
}

public static void commit(Context context, String key, Object value) {
    getDefaultInstance(context).commit(key, value);
}

public static DroidPrefs getDefaultInstance(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return new DroidPrefs(sp);
}

private Gson mGson;

private SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;

public DroidPrefs(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs)
{
    mGson = new Gson();
    mSharedPrefs = sharedPrefs;
}

public boolean contains(String key) {
    return mSharedPrefs.contains(key);
}

public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> cls) {
    if (contains(key)) {
        return mGson.fromJson(mSharedPrefs.getString(key, null), cls);
    }

    try {
        return cls.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("class must have an empty constructor");
    }
}

public void apply(String key, Object value) {
    put(key, value).apply();
}

public void commit(String key, Object value) {
    put(key, value).commit();
}

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
private SharedPreferences.Editor put(String key, Object value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPrefs.edit();
    e.putString(key, mGson.toJson(value));
    return e;
}

public void clear(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPrefs.edit();
    e.clear().apply();
    }
}
```

You can save value to any key by using apply or commit method

```
DroidPrefs.apply(context, "your key", yourobject);
```

You can fetch value by using get method

```
yourobject= DroidPrefs.get(this,"your key",yourclass.class);
```

Comment: No you can't as SharedPreferences are **not** made to pass data between components but to store data you want the app to retrieve after being closed.